# Proving Archimedes Sequences Equal $\pi$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, pi

I encountered the following problem in my text An Introduction to Analysis by William Wade. It was the last problem in the section and has an * next to it. I'm not sure if this indicates a challenge problem or that this problem is of some significance. The sequences, I  believe, are suppose to equal $\pi$, so that is suggesting to me it's more of a significance.

I tried searching for the problem, as I figured anything that equals $\pi$ is no coincidence and must be a famous example. But, 'Archimedes Pi Sequence' and other variants yield much different results than this problem. I was hoping someone could either provide a link to the proof (assuming it is indeed famous) or provide a relative outline so I could try to follow along/work through it.

The problem is:

**[Archimedes]** Suppose that $x_0=2\sqrt{3}, \quad y_0=3$,
$$x_n=\frac{2x_{n-1}y_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}+y_{n-1}},$$
and
$$y_n=\sqrt{x_{n}\cdot y_{n-1}}$$
for $n\in \mathbb N$.

Prove that $x_n \downarrow x$ and $y_n \uparrow y$, as $n\to \infty$, for some $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Next, prove $x=y$ and that $3.14155\lt x\lt 3.14161$. (This is why I believe $x=y=\pi$)

Edit: I understand that if we can show $x_n$ is decreasing and converging to $x$, and $y_n$ is increasing and converging to $y$, we can recognize the Monotone Convergence Theorem. After which, apply the limit to both equations to get $x$ and $y$. The problem I am having is understanding how we get there, and after we are there, how we show it equals $\pi$. Though, if I understand how we get there the $\pi$ part might come together.

Comment: I misread the second recursion dealing with $y_{n}$ and thought it to be related to AGM. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time nonetheless.

Comment: Usually it says somewhere in a book what an asterisk next to a problem means. In the preface, or the introduction, or the first time it pops up in an exercise.

Comment: So, have you had a look to see what the asterisk means?

Answer (score 6):

The limit is in fact $\pi$.

Hint:

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be the half the perimeter of the of the inscribed and circumscribed $n$-gons of the unit circle. Then

$$b_{2n}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n},$$

$$a_{2n}=\sqrt{b_{n+1}a_n}.$$

Further, $b_3=2\sqrt3$.

Historical note: Gauss used a similar process to compute (approximate) values of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Your answer may be a bit beyond me.

Comment: @Vincent Are you familiar with the famous way Archimedes approximated $\pi$ by using inscribed polygons?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not. I've been attempting to do/understand this problem through showing $x_n \downarrow x$ and $y_n \uparrow y$. Unfortunately, that is the only means I have at my disposal (that I can think of).

Comment: @Vincent I see. Well, it's quite classic, and once you understand it, you'll be able to do this problem! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion

Comment: Well, after a couple more hours, I was able to show $x_n\downarrow x$ and $y_n \uparrow y$ and that $x=y$. Now, I have absolutely no idea how to show that it's $\pi$.

Comment: x_n> harmonic(x_n,y_n) > geometric(x_n,y_n-1) > y_n

Comment: @Vincent Have you tried the geometric interpretation I suggested? Because it works to show the limit is $\pi$!