# How to show sequence converges to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pi

The question is as follows:

> Let $a_{0} = 2\sqrt{3}$ and $b_{0} = 3$ and define two sequences
> recursivly as $$a_{n} = \frac{2a_{n - 1}\cdot b_{n - 1}}{a_{n - 1} +
>  b_{n - 1}} \text{    and    }b_{n} = \sqrt{a_{n}b_{n - 1}}$$
>
> Prove that $(a_{n})$ is monotonically decreasing and is convergent.
> and prove that $(b_{n})$ is monotonically increasing and convergent.
> Then prove that they converge to $\pi$.

I managed to prove that the sequences are convergent and monotonically increasing/decreasing but I do not know how to prove they converge to $\pi$. Further, I do not have a rigorous definition for $\pi$, I only know that it is the area of a circle of radious $1$. **The question also mentions as a hint that it is somehow related to Archimedes**.

Comment: Seems related to [Proving Archimedes Sequences Equal $\pi$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/937564/89922)

Comment: Are you familiar with how archimedes calculated pi? https://youtu.be/gMlf1ELvRzc?si=KyQV-gISxk6XHgyA&t=103

Comment: Perimeters of inscribed and circumscribed regular polygons, starting with the hexagon and doubling the number of sides. Archimedes used four doublings to bound $\pi$ between $3\frac{10}{71}$ and $3\frac17$.